# navigation between 2 fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have 2 fragments A and B in my application.
the mainactivity starts up with fragment A. on pressing a button in it i replace it with fragment B.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
B_Fragment pfrag = new B_Fragment();
pfrag.setArguments(args);
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag_container, pfrag)
        .addToBackStack("A_Fragment").commit();
```

Now in fragment B i press a button to replace it with fragment A using:

```
fm.popBackStack();
fm.beginTransaction().addToBackStack("B_fragment").commit();
```

Fragment A is successfully pushed and popped from the stack where as fragment B is not.
Every time B_fragment is been destroyed and a new one is created.
So can someone tell me what i am missing and how to push fragment B onto the stack and pop A out at the same time.

Comment: As far as I'm aware `replace()` calls `remove()` on the existing fragment which will destroy it. Instead of `replace()` try to `hide()`  the existing and then `add()` the new one.

Comment: from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html->Note-> When you remove or replace a fragment and add the transaction to the back stack, the fragment that is removed is stopped (not destroyed). If the user navigates back to restore the fragment, it restarts

Answer (score 2):

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
B_Fragment pfrag = new B_Fragment();
pfrag.setArguments(args);
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag_container, pfrag).commit();
```

On `Fragment B`, why don't just replace it with `Fragment A`

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.pnlLeft, details);
ft.commit();
```

`popBackStack` does not load the last fragment, it's commonly used to pop the entire stack :

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

> before loading another fragment

```
beginTransaction()
replace() Or add()
commit()
```

When you press `the button in Fragment B`, try the below code. This will re-load the `entire fragment`.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
    fm.popBackStack();
}
```

Comment: i tried it but the onDestroy and onDetach method of my fragment B is still been called implying that it is not pushed on the stack

Comment: Why do override onDestroy method? Try the update and let me know.

Comment: just to check whether it is pushed on stack or not. Fragment A is properly pushed and popped.  for some reason fragment B is not been pushed.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, why do you want to push Fragment B. You load  the Fragment B from A and a is in the stack, now when you press Button from Fragment B... A loads again through popBackStack() from there you again call the Fragment B....